# Update post through function based view in Django

Tags: django, forms, simplemodal, templatetags

I have searched for an answer to this over and over now and can't find a response that relates to my issue.

I have a modal in my home page which I would like to allow users to update their posts from. I am using an inclusion tag and fbv for this.

Here is my view:

```
def update_view(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)

    if 'submit_u_form' in request.POST:
        u_form = PostUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance=post)
        if u_form.is_valid():
             u_form.save()

    return redirect('posts:index')
```

And here is my custom tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('posts/update.html')
def update_tag():
    u_form = PostUpdateForm()
    return {'u_form': u_form}
```

Forms.py is here:

```
class PostUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['content', 'image', 'category',]
```

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('update/', update_view, name='update'),
]
```

My modal in index.html includes this form:

```
<form action="{% url 'posts:update' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={{ post.id }}>
        {% update_tag %}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_u_form">Update Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And update.html simply contains `{{ u_form }}`

My form shows up in the modal how I would like it to however upon submit I receive this error:

`TypeError at /update/`
`Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.`

I have tried passing the id to the url with `<int:id>` but that only lead to further errors.

Please can someone explain to me where I have gone wrong and how I can resolve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

change your view to

```
def update_view(request,id):#id
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostUpdateForm(instance=post)
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = PostUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=post)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
```

change your url to

```
path('update/<int:id>', update_view, name='update'),
```

Comment: to me its annoying that django still uses a POST method in a PUT request, it does not make any sense at all, its the most silly architecture